# Saving Git Push to an output file

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I'm new to Git.

My problem is, with a shell script (running in Windows) I need to save the Git  Push commands to an output file.

So far i've something like this:

```
echo -e "\n6) ${GREEN}Starting Push.${NC}"
git push -v >> logs/logPush.log

if grep -q -w -i "Rejected" logs/logPush.log ; 
then 
    echo "${RED}A conflict has been detected. Exiting.${NC}" 
    read
    exit
else
    :
fi
```

But it always generates a blank file. The Pull works just fine tho...

Does anyone know how to make the output file receive the whole information that it appears on the terminal:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh:repository
   42be914..ead1f82  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A UNIX shell provides two output streams by default -- stdout and stderr.

This is often useful because when you redirect output to something else, you still want errors to go to the screen.

```
 $ cat nosuchfile | grep something
 cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
```

This is what I wanted. I didn't want `cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory` to be fed into `grep`.

As you know, you can redirect stdout using `>` and `|`.

You can redirect stderr using `2>`:

```
$ cat nosuchfile > outfile 2>errormessage
```

A common idiom is:

```
$ somecommand > output 2>&1
```

Here `&1` refers to the *file descriptor* used by stdout. So you're telling the shell to send stderr to the same place as stdout.

You can use `2>&1` to send stderr to your output file. Or you can use what you've learned here to make sense of the git documentation re `--porcelain`, or design some other solution, for example sending stderr to a second file where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete example!

Answer (score 8):

Redirect stderr to the file as well:

```
git push -v >> logs/logPush.log 2>&1
```

It looks like `git push` has the `--porcelain` option for this purpose:

> --porcelain
>
> Produce machine-readable output. The output status line for each ref will be tab-separated and sent to stdout instead of stderr.
>   The full symbolic names of the refs will be given.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the exit status of `git push` will indicate whether it was successful or not. You should use it rather than parsing the log:

```
if ! git push -v >> logs/logPush.log 2>&1
then 
    echo "${RED}Failed to push. Exiting.${NC}" 
    read
    exit
fi
```

I've used `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout, so the log would contain both outputs - this is optional.

If the command fails, it's not necessarily indicative of a conflict, so I modified the error message to something more generic.

Comment: This is the right way to do it.  You should not rely on information intended for humans to read - it would break if git was translated into another language